# Lua script broke

Tags: lua

In the lua script, an error was thrown attempt to index global 'db' (a nil value) I don't understand what the problem is, how do I make a global zero value

```
function bindFunction()
    while true do wait(0)
        if isKeysDown(db["MESSAGE"]["deliveryClient"]["v"]) then
            if db["MESSAGE"]["deliveryClient"]["ACTIVE"] and #db["MESSAGE"]["deliveryClient"]["TEXT"] > 0 and takedCall["ACTIVE"] then
                for key, val in ipairs(db["MESSAGE"]["deliveryClient"]["TEXT"]) do
                    if val:find("^%{WAIT-%d+%}$") then
                        local num = val:match("%{WAIT-(%d+)%}")
                        wait(num * 1000)
                    else
                        sampSendChat(replaceText(val))
                    end
                end
            end
            takedCall["ACTIVE"] = false
            takedCall["NAME"] = ""
        end
    end
end
```

I tried to enter local db == 0 then, it seemed to be solved, but then it gave another error, or the same

Comment: What framework/software this Lua script is written for?